# How to implement laravel 5 and ldap authentication

Tags: laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to find a simple tutorial/guide to setup a login page using ldap.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel is using composer, I would consider to use one composer package from https://packagist.org/search/?q=ldap